# How to structure these relations?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `tablet`, with a column `period_id`. The `tablet` table has a many-to-one relationship with a `period` table, and the `period` table has a one-to-many relationship with a `sub_period` table. I need to be able to specify a single `sub_period` entry in or from `tablet`, the choice of which is restricted by the `period` entry, but since `sub_period` only depends on `period`, I can't. How should I model this?

In my model, each `tablet` row should have one `period` entry, and one `sub_period` entry. The relationship between `period` and `sub_period` should be `1:n` (a period may have many sub-periods, but each sub-period can only belong to a single period). The `sub-period`s I'd like to be able to choose from in `tablet` should be restricted by my choice of `period`

Edit: Have realised that I need an N:1 relationship between `tablet` and `period`: many tablets can relate to the same period.

Comment: The question is what is supposed to be this entry of subperiod into your tablet table? Functionnaly

Comment: How does `sub_period` record its relationship with `period`?  Surely it also has a `period_id` column?  In which case, can't you just [join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) `tablet` directly to `sub_period` on that column?

Comment: @sebas It would be one of a subset of records from sub_period, depending on what period was chosen. Let's say there are two periods: A and B. period A has sub_periods sp_A_1 and sp_A_2, period B has sub_periods sp_A_3 and sp_A_4. If my tablet entry links to period A, I should then only be able to choose between sp_A_1 and sp_A_2.

Comment: @urschrei: in your example above, can you have two different tablets, one linked to `sp_A_1`, another one linked to `sp_A_2`?

Comment: @Quassnoi Yep, see my edits. I've just realised that I need N:1 between tablet and period.

Comment: @urschrei: can many tablets refer to one `sub_period`?

Comment: @Quassnoi Yes, they can.

Answer (score 2):

Create a nullable column `has_tablet ENUM('1')` in `sub_period` and create a `UNIQUE` constraint on `sub_period (period, has_tablet)`.

`has_tablet` can only accept values `1` or `NULL` which means you can set exactly one season per period as "having the tablet". Since `period` to `tablet` is one-to-one, this uniquely identifies the `tablet` too.

It is possible not to set any tablet for a period at all with this solution. If it's a problem, add `period` to `tablet` and make `tablet (period, sub_period)` reference `sub_period (period, sub_period)`.

This is a denormalization but it can never lead to an inconsistency (since the `period` is defined by `sub_period` in both tables).

**Update:**

Seems that period to tablet is one-to-many. In this case, just add make `tablet` reference `sub_period` rather than `period`. `period` relationship can be transitively inferred by a simple join.

Comment: The problem here is that several tablets could relate to the same sub-period within a given period, so your "one season per period" is too restrictive. As such, the only restriction I need is that you shouldn't be able to choose a sub-period which isn't part of the "many" side of the period you chose.

Comment: @urschrei: But... you said it was a 1-to-1 relationship between `tablet` and `period`. If many tablets were referencing the same sub-period, they would also have to be referencing the same period, which would contradict the 1-to-1 tablet/period relationship. What am I missing?

Comment: @AndriyM This is where I'm getting confused. Each row can only have a single period entry, and a single sub-period entry. But this solution implies that if I link a tablet record to a sub-period once, I can't link any other tablets to that sub-period. Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: @urschrei: Or *I* am misunderstanding your requirements. How about an example? Preferably in your question post, please. I know you did give an example in the other comment, but maybe you could extend it a bit to cover your multiple tablets case and what you mean by referencing the same sub_period (and format things nicely too, which you can't do in a comment).

Comment: @urschrei: Thanks. To be honest, your update doesn't improve my understanding of the issue. I mean, it doesn't detract from it either, and as far as I can see both Quassnoi's suggestions are still applicable. But because misunderstandings have arisen, it would be better if you provided an example. A short sample of `period` and corresponding samples of `sub_period` and `tablet` with relevant columns and an explanation about what should be restricted to what for which entry, would probably suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Then you have 2 options:

- database layer: implement consistency contraints through triggers. after insert or update, if sub_pediod is not a sub_period of the tablet's period, raise the appropriate error.
- applicative layer: implement the proper GUI to provide the right choices only, whenever it is necessary.

The second option is my favorite whenever it is about non sensitive data (keep in mind somebody could always skip the client interface), because it usually gives me more "range of motion" with how I want to deal with the problem. Of course there are always exceptions...

Answer (score 0):

When you are modeling you, normally you don't create 1:1 relations, when you normalize you'll get notice that the table with relation 1:1 you can match them into a table, this is how I see it:
if you have 3 tables with relations

- **tablet** 1:n **sub_period**
- **tablet** 1:1 **period**

(the keys in the graphic are the primaries keys and the red symbol is the foreign key)

[image]

or you can make a match between the **Tablet** and **Period** table and the model will look like this

[image]

where **Tablet** absorb **Period** with all his attributes, but that's  up to you, the model you have to adapt it to your needs.